# Cannot change field type from text to date after field is used in concat - mysql

Tags: mysql, date, format, type-conversion, concatenation

In a table, I created a new field/column then set the column to populate as a concat of two other fields.  The two fields used in the concat are text fields.  I executed the concat just fine.  However, I need to convert one of the two text fields used in the concat to a date format (the field values are already populated as dates but in text format).  When I change the format of the field from text to date, it results in the column populating with all zeros in date format (00-00-0000).  Initially, I figured this was somehow being caused by the concat the field used to populate (even though theoretically it shouldn't), so I deleted the field/column where the concat was populating, went back and changed the format of the field from text to date, and this resulted in the field values all changing to zeros once again (00-00-0000).

In troubleshooting this issue, I found that it is possible to change the desired field's format to types other than date (for example from varchar to bigint or text).  If I change the format before executing the concat, the format changes from text to date perfectly fine; so it seems as though once the text field is used in the concat, something happens to the integrity of the field values so that if the text field is converted to a date field after the text field is used in a concat, the values will change to 00-00-0000.  In addition, I created a new empty column, copied the text column that I want to convert to a date, and pasted it in the empty column; the data pastes exactly how it is, but then when I change the format the field values change to 00-00-0000 again.

In a total of five DB tables comprised of over 80M total rows, I created an additional column and ran concats that use two fields in each table to populate the new column.  The fields used in the concat are both text fields and the field populated with the concat is a varchar field.

I'm in the very early stages of building this database, so if the only logical solution to this problem is to delete the database and recreate it, I will do so; however, finding a solution that doesn't involve deleting and loading the data in again, without compromising the DB's integrity as a whole, would be ideal.

I'm running an RDS Aurora DB w/ an InnoDB storage engine and using Navicat mysql as a DBMS.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you might be able to provide regarding this issue.

Comment: no, you wouldn't get 00-00-0000 in a date field. mysql's date-as-string format is 0000-00-00. and if you get that after converting a text type to a date them, then your dates-as text are NOT in a format that mysql recognizes, which is basically `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` **ONLY**. you get the all-zeroes version  as a fallback and indicates there was a conversion failure.

Comment: In Navicat I have the date format changed to mm-dd-yyyy, under the global settings.

Comment: that's a display format, and has nothing to do with how mysql stores strings-as-dates internally.

Comment: In troubleshooting this, I loaded a sample of the same data into a separate table and had it originally formatted as text upon loading.  After it loaded and the text fields displayed exactly how the date would, I changed the field format to date and this successfully converted the field values to date format.  So I don't think its a formatting issue w/ the raw field data.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that these dates are all correct and formatted as mm-dd-yyyy.  So how would it be a formatting issue?

Comment: I am viewing the data in Navicat, so maybe thats why its still displaying as 00-00-0000?  As I mentioned in my initial question, when I load the same data into a text field, I have no issues converting the field type to date and sorting the rows by date.  I only encounter this problem after using the field in a concat; so formatting issues aside, clearly there is something happening to that column of values that restricts me from converting the field to date, if Im able to successfully change the format before executing the concat.

Comment: well, show what you're doing in this concat() call...the actual query(s) you're using.

Comment: Marc, I understand what you are saying, but if it was solely a formatting issue, then the field values would turn to 00-00-0000 when I change format type before running the concat, which is not the case.  When I change the field type from text to date without executing the concat, the values do not change to zeros.

Comment: UPDATE table_name SET field_name = CONCAT(field1,field2);

Comment: Before executing the above concat, I created the field (field_name) where the concat populates

Comment: the single quote in the concat is a typo in the example, but not an error in the actual syntax I ran

Comment: and this `field_Name` is the field you're converting text->date? field1 is date, field2 is time? or what?

Comment: field1 is a 17 digit # formatted as a bigint, and field2 is the date in question.  So field2 is the field Im converting from text->date

Comment: I apologize, field1 is a 17 digit # formatted as varchar

Comment: reading a field does NOT change its value.

Comment: If your referencing me correcting the format type, I just wanted to give you the exact info, otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean..

Comment: So I guess you can't figure it out either Marc?

Comment: After running numerous tests, it appears that Marc's opinion that this is a formatting issue is incorrect.  Although I did not figure out a way to convert the original column from text to date, I did figure out a workaround.

Comment: well, since you refused to show any actual code and only offered vague descriptions of the problem, what else did you expect?

Comment: Create a new column and format it to "date".  Then set the new column as follows:    <code> db_name.table_name SET STR_TO_DATE(field_name,%m/%d/%Y); </code>  This will successfully copy all the field values from the text column to the new column in date format.

Comment: Huh?  I sent the concat script right after you asked for it.  please check the comments.